# MySQL: Optimize greatest row in group query

Tags: mysql, indexing, greatest-n-per-group

I have table `Addresses` with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `Address` (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_Person INT NOT NULL,
    Street VARCHAR(50),
    HouseNumber VARCHAR(10),
    City VARCHAR(50),
    Zipcode CHAR(5),
    Country CHAR(2),
    Version INT,
    ValidFrom DATE,
    ValidTo DATE,
);
```

Each address belongs to user (`ID_Person`) and each user can have multiple addreses. Each address has `Version`, which is `INT`, one user can have multiple addresses with same version. I want to retrieve address with the highest `Version` for each user. In case of multiple highest versions for one user, address can be chosen randomly from highest values.

What I have done, is following:

I get highest version of address for each user:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_highest_addresses AS
SELECT 
    ID,
    ID_Person,
    Max(Version) AS Version
FROM
    Address
WHERE ValidTo IS NULL OR ValidTo < NOW()
GROUP BY ID_Person
```

And then join addreses based on combination of `ID_Person` and `Version`

```
CREATE VIEW vw_addresses AS
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    a.ID_Person,
    a.Street,
    a.HouseNumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode,
    a.Country,
    a.Version
FROM
    Address AS a, vw_primary_addresses AS aprimary
WHERE
    a.ID_Person = aprimary.ID_Person
  AND a.Version = aprimary.Version
  AND a.ValidTo IS NULL OR a.ValidTo < NOW()
GROUP BY a.ID_Person;
```

I have this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_addresses ON Address(ID_Person, IsPrimary, ValidTo)
```

This provides correct results, but is very slow (6000 row in addresses takes 6 sec to perform query)

Here is query execution plan:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL    5936    
2   DERIVED     a           ALL     idx_addresses   NULL            NULL        NULL    5565    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     <derived3>  ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL    5936    Using where; Using join buffer
3   DERIVED     a           index   NULL            idx_addresses   10          NULL    5565    Using where; Using index
```

How can I optimize the query?

Comment: But no two people can share the same address? What a lonely little place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not correct because of the precedence of `AND` and `OR`. `AND` hash higher precedence, so it's being treated as if you'd written.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_addresses AS
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    a.ID_Person,
    a.Street,
    a.HouseNumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode,
    a.Country,
    a.Version
FROM
    Address AS a, vw_primary_addresses AS aprimary
WHERE
    (a.ID_Person = aprimary.ID_Person
        AND a.Version = aprimary.Version
        AND a.ValidTo IS NULL)
    OR a.ValidTo < NOW()
GROUP BY a.ID_Person;
```

So everyone with `ValidTo < NOW()` is being returned as a cross-product in addition to the ones that match the joining condition.

It would be better if you wrote it as an explicit `JOIN`, then you wouldn't run into this problem.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_addresses AS
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    a.ID_Person,
    a.Street,
    a.HouseNumber,
    a.City,
    a.Zipcode,
    a.Country,
    a.Version
FROM
    Address AS a
JOIN 
    vw_primary_addresses AS aprimary
ON
    a.ID_Person = aprimary.ID_Person
  AND a.Version = aprimary.Version
WHERE 
  a.ValidTo IS NULL OR a.ValidTo < NOW()
GROUP BY a.ID_Person;
```

Note that if there's multiple addresses with the same version, your `SELECT` might select different columns from different addresses. To solve that you need another level of subquery.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_addresses_id AS
SELECT 
    MAX(a.ID) AS id
FROM
    Address AS a
JOIN 
    vw_primary_addresses AS aprimary
ON
    a.ID_Person = aprimary.ID_Person
  AND a.Version = aprimary.Version
WHERE 
  a.ValidTo IS NULL OR a.ValidTo < NOW()
GROUP BY a.ID_Person;

CREATE VIEW vw_addresses AS
SELECT a.*
FROM Address AS a
JOIN vw_addresses_id AS aprimary
ON a.ID = aprimary.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm, performs query in 0.03 sec - and thanks for pointing out logical operator preference, I have entirely missed it